# Why does a web app access through an SSLVPN gateway not work?

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, glassfish, primefaces

I have an issue with a JSF2 web application using PrimeFaces 3.2.  Our organization has a Nortel VPN Gateway 3050 that we want to use as a single point of access for our external users.  We have added a link on the landing page to point to the internal server and the navigation to the login page appears to function correctly most of the time.  However, it does not function correctly.

Using Fiddler, I found that I am getting errors when trying to download the PrimeFaces CSS and jQuery JavaScript files.  I also receive an error "The connection was reset whenever" I try to log in.  This error also appears sporadically on the initial navigation from the landing page but it is not consistent.

The web application itself is running on a dedicated VM using Windows Server 2008R2 and GlassFish listening on port 80.  The SSL authentication is using AD; the users reauthenticate using their AD credentials within the application.

Is there configuration changes I need to make on the GlassFish side to allow the web application to function behind the gateway?  The app runs fine on the internal network.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Chris

UPDATE:
It looks like the error occurs when trying to load the primefaces.js and jquery.js files; I get JavaScript errors saying objects are not defined.  If I try to force the 2 JS files to load first, I get similar errors with the xnet JavaScript.  Our network specialist has no information how the appliance works internally (he inherited it from someone else and we do not leverage it for many things).

I deployed a bare bones app that simply includes a p:commandButton and still receive the errors, so I know it isn't anything in particular with the other code base.

Looks like I may need to rip out all the PrimeFaces goodness redevelop the app using only core components and hope for the best.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this might contain an answer, but I stumbled upon [this](http://downloads.avaya.com/css/P8/documents/100103064) documentation containing the following text:

> Fixed problem with NVG sending compressed xnet.js file to a Microsoft
>   IE 5.5 client. Microsoft IE 5.5 has a compression bug (see MS
>   knowledge base #313712) causing the browser to drop the first 2048
>   bytes of compressed data. There is a setting in the CLI which governs
>   if the NVG produces compressed content to the client or not. When set
>   to off (default value), no compressed content is sent to the client
>   browser. When set to on, the content from the intranet and from the
>   NVG will be compressed if the client browser accepts compressed
>   content. This change makes the NVG portal code take into account this
>   setting when delivering the Javascript file xnet.js to the client. (CR
>   Q01270920)

So might there be an issue with minified Javascript files??

BTW something similar in this [documentation](http://downloads.avaya.com/css/P8/documents/100100108)

> Q01982756 Enabling http compression causes xnet.js JavaScript to fail
>   to decompress in IE
>   6.0. This issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the VPN connection. Is all network traffic directed trough the VPN connection or only the traffic towards the webserver?

Use tools like http://www.wireshark.org/ to analyse the application network traffic, or use the tools provided by Nortel.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to any of the tools (or to the appliance itself) and our network guy does not really know how to do anything with the appliance, other than adding the link pointing resource.  We have other web applications that are accessed via the same SSL page that function fine.

Comment: You said that you get an error when loading css or javascript files. When you browse to the css or js files do they load?

Comment: No, I just get the connection is reset error.  One thing I failed to mention is the images do not load either.

Comment: I advise you to take a chair and to sit down next to your network spcialist. Or that you write a proof of concept for him to test the problem.

Comment: Thanks, we were going to sit down next week to try and troubleshoot it.  I just wanted to do some checking on my own to try and pinpoint the exact issue.